# Блочное шифрование в различных режимах

Tags: c#, криптография

Необходимо написать программу  на C# для шифрования (расшифрования) файлов с помощью блочного шифра в различных режимах (ECB, CBC, OFB, CTR, CFB). Подскажите литературу или ссылки на сайты, где об этих режимах можно почитать в подробностях и как программно реализовываются эти режимы.

Answer (score 2):

Погуглите ключевое слово *cipher mode* или *block cipher mode* - а англоязычной литературе режимы блочного шифрования принято обозначать термином *mode*

Вообще [прекрасная статья есть в Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) - мне кажется  реализовать эти схемы в C# проще простого

Answer (score 0):

поищите книгу шнайер "прикладная криптография" он очень доступно излагает. возможно все режимы блочного шифрования и не будут в ней описаны, но об отличиях можно разобратся и на вики.

а что касается реализации то практически все режимы можно реализовать с помощью des (реализаций коего полным полно в тырнете).

Comment: >все режимы можно реализовать с помощью des

C этого места подробнее. Причем тут режимы и DES? :)